# How to use an array containing Pair objects?

Tags: java, arrays, keyvaluepair

My array:

```
private Object[] arr = new Pair[initialCapacity];
```

My Pair class:

```
private static class Pair<V> {
    private String key;
    private V value;

    public Pair(String key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the properties of the objects like this:

```
arr[startPos].key
```

but I get the error "cannot find symbol - variable key"

Comment: Don't declare the array an array of Object, since even though you assigned a Pair array to the variable, Java only knows that the variable holds Objects

Comment: Rather, declare it `private Pair[] arr = new Pair[initialCapacity];`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I declared it like Pair[] instead and now I can find the key, but still not the value?

Comment: I suggest a second duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: If you need key value pairs why not use a Map? Arrays only know int indices and are not best for your situation

Comment: The task wants me to use an array @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: You also need to give the class public getter and possibly setter methods

Comment: And the raw type will bite OP as well, can you add that as a duplicate as well @HovercraftFullOfEels ?

Comment: @luk, yes, you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/522444), and you of course are correct, but I can't right now since I am on my phone, and the phone app has limitations

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels obtaining the key works now, but I can't get the value, it says "incompatible types: java.lang.object cannot be converted to V"

Comment: Read this: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)